# is there any concept like 9 png (android) in java AWT..?

Tags: java, android, swing, awt

I am new to `AWT` UI development, and I have experience building apps for android. So naturally I am relating the UI components from both of them.

Currently I am developing a desktop application where I want have an `ImageButton`. In `Android` we generally use `.9.png` images for that, it is handy and has it's own [advantages](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch).

My question is, is there any concept of .9.png in java AWT.

Comment: part of JComponets has method setIcon, most of (from this part) with alignment

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything like that on J2SE, specially using AWT.

AWT is old. If you have the choice, I recommend you to use Swing instead.